# rsync to Windows Server NTFS share always copies all files/folders

Tags: ubuntu, windows, rsync, smb

I am using rsync to backup the /var/www/ folder on my Lubuntu 20.04 host to an NTFS share on a Windows 2022 Server. The command below always copies every file and folder, despite the fact that no changes have been made:

```
rsync -av "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"
```

I've tried the options below, but it made no difference:

```
rsync -av --modify-window=1 "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"

rsync -av --checksum "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"

rsync -av  --no-p --no-g --chmod=ugo=rwX "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"
```

Any ideas for how I can sync only new or modified files/folders?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you run `stat` on a file located under the NTFS share, does it report a Modify time?

Comment: Yes - e.g. "Modify: 2007-11-16 23:38:01.000000000 +0000" for one of the files